# How to simply use console commands in a c++ program?

Tags: c++

I am doing an exercise that requires me to use the **wc** console command to list the number of words in a specified file, after the user has entered the file's name. How can this be done?

Here is some code I'v managed so far:

```
int main()
{
    string filename;
    string cmd1,cmd2,cmd3;


    cout<<"Please enter a filename: ";
    getline(cin, filename);


    cmd1="wc -l " +filename;        //lines
    cmd2="wc -w " + filename;   //words
    cmd3="wc -c "+filename;   //bytes
    /

    cout<<system("\\cmd1\\")<<endl;   //does not work

    cout<<system("wc -l device_data.txt")<<endl;   //works


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this `system(cmd1)`

Comment: You have a line marked as "works". Is there still some problem with it?

Comment: using system(cmd1) gives me an error.

Comment: `system(cmd1.c_str())`

Comment: the line that has "works" is working, but it is if I manually enter the filename. I want the "device_data.txt" part to act as a variable, so if a user enters a filename, it can list the words of any file

Comment: system(cmd1.c_str())  made it work, but why?

Comment: signature is `int system( const char * syscom );`, not `system(std::string)`

Answer (score 2):

The `system` function returns an integer which is the return value of the executed shell.

What you want is to get the output of your command which can be done with:

```
int main()
{   
    std::string filename{"x.txt"};
    std::string command{"wc -l "};
    command+=filename;

    char buffer[10000];
    FILE *f = popen(command.c_str(), "r");
    while ( fgets(buffer, 10000, f) != nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    }

    pclose( f );
    return 0 ; 
}
```

You should read the man pages before typing the source code ;)

Comment: Don't forget to `pclose(f)` afterwards :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Oh yeah! ;) I am lucky that my os will close it also if I exit, but you are rigt, it is bad as an example for a newbie! Thanks! Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do :

```
std::string f;
cin>>f;

std::string c1 = "wc -l " + f;
std::string c2 = "wc -w " + f;
std::string c3 = "wc -c " + f;

cout<<system(c1.c_str())<<endl;
cout<<system(c2.c_str())<<endl;
cout<<system(c3.c_str())<<endl;
```

Here the thing is system takes char* as parameter and you were using string datatype .

Answer (score 0):

> use the wc console command to list the number of words in a 
>   specified file, after the user has entered the file's name. How 
>   can this be done?

On Linux, and with in my C++ programs, I use popen.  Here is a snippet of code (part of class Metric_v05) which compiles.

```
// retrieve what wc reports
void Metric_v05::getRawLocCount (std::string aPfn,
                                 uint32_t&   lineCount,
                                 uint32_t&   wordCount,
                                 uint32_t&   byteCount)
{
   std::string cmd;

   cmd = "wc " + aPfn;

   // use pipe to invoke the command and retrieve results
   FILE* pipe = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");

   do
   {
      if(0 == pipe) break; // skip over pclose()

      std::stringstream ss;
      {
         char buff[1024]; // assume all these lines will be shorter than this (C-ism)
         memset(buff, 0, 1024);

         // read output from pipe
         if (0 == fgets(buff, 1024, pipe))
         {
            // break out when no more output at pipe
            std::cout << "line word byte ?" << std::endl;
            pclose(pipe);
            break; // queue complete, eof, kick out
         }
         ss << buff;
      }

      // output of wc / input to the buff is "line word byte", such as:
      //  1257    4546   44886

      ss >> lineCount >> wordCount >> byteCount;
      // TBR - stat = ss >> xxx; if(!stat) break;
      // I would normally recommend status check,
      // but wc is quite reliable.

      if (false)  // diagnostic disabled
         std::cout << "lwb: "
                   << lineCount << " "
                   << wordCount << " "
                   << byteCount << std::endl;

      // be sure to
      pclose(pipe);

   } while (0); // only 1 line to fetch, drop any others.

} // void Metric_v05::getRawLocCount (...)
```